# Sequelize: Custom Date Format in SQLite Database

Tags: typescript, sqlite, date, sequelize.js

I have a column in an SQLite database with a `DATE` Sequelize type:

```js
modified:{ type: DataTypes.DATE }
```

Just before saving an object, I get the date for "now" like this:

```js
object.modified = new Date()

await MyType.upsert(object)
```

Everything looks good up until here, but when I view the data in an SQLite viewer app, I see this date format:

```js
//JavaScript date Format in SQLite
2022-06-14 18:52:44.816 +00:00
```

...but in order for it to be compatible with my corresponding Swift app, I need it to be in this format:

```js
//Swift date format in SQLite
2022-06-14T18:52:44.816
```

The only way I have found to get the same format in my JS app is to save the date as a string with [Day.js](https://day.js.org/) like this: `dayjs(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss[.]SSS')`.

How can I have a custom date format for a Sequelize `DATE` in SQLite?

Comment: You can possibly create a custom extension to enforce the format you want.  https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/extending-data-types/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize's DATE datatype defaults to that date + time + offset format. If you have the date format that you want available to you in the database software (Either out of the box or custom-created), you can [extend Sequelize's datatypes](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/extending-data-types/). It's relatively painless code to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I started writing my question last night and came up with a potential solution today, so I thought I'd share it. It may not be the right way to do this, but it seems to work.

In order to have a custom format for my `modified` date column, I can use a [Sequelize getter and setter](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/getters-setters-virtuals/) in my data type definitions.

```js
import { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize'
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

modified: { 
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  //Whenever modified is retrieved from the DB, format the string to a date object
  get(){
    return dayjs(this.getDataValue('modified'), 'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss[.]SSS')
  },
  //Whenever modified is saved, format the date object to my custom string format
  set(value){
    this.setDataValue('modified', dayjs(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss[.]SSS'))
  }
}
```

Comment: The only thing I would add is that you should probably keep the internal DB type as DATE. This will allow for date specific optimizations and queries, instead of slow casting each time. I believe the only change you would need to make is wrapping `this.getDataValue('modified')` in `new Date(this.getDataValue('modified'))` on the getter, unless dayjs automatically casts (I'm used to date-fns which doesn't).

Comment: My challenge with using the `DATE` Sequelize type is that my Swift app requires the date to use that specific format. Under the hood, an SQLite date is a `TEXT`, and in Swift it won't be able to convert it to a `Date` object unless it's that format. Sequelize's `DATE` types **only** allow their specific format for a date. 

Comment: I'm hoping that when I query my Sequelize database (like filtering based on the date), that it uses the value returned by the getter.

Comment: Could you just use the ISO 8601 parser on the Swift side?
```let fmt= ISO8601DateFormatter()
let date = fmt.date(from:sequelizeDate)!
```

Comment: I'm using SQLite.swift and it seems to hard-code a specific date format for interpreting SQLite dates: https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/70fb7af324cb3170d921f135f0c84cbdb6487cc2/Sources/SQLite/Foundation.swift#L66